# How to remove anything that starts with specific character (@) in various locations in string in R?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a column that contains multiple tweets:

```
ID | Tweet
1    @ChipotleTweets @ChipotleTweets Becky is very nice
2    Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at @ChipotleTweets
3    Considering walking to @.ChipotleTweets in my llama onesie.
```

The goal is to remove the '@___' and anything that is after @ - but not the text spaced outside that string.

Playing around this code currently to detect '@' but I am not picking up anything if it's not in the first position of the sentence

```
tweet_pattern <- " @\\w+"

Customer <- Customer %>% 
           clean_Tweet = ifelse(str_detect(text, tweet_pattern), 
                                str_remove(text, tweet_pattern), 
                                NA_character_))
```

Desired output:

```
ID | Tweet                                                                  | cleaned_tweet 
1    @ChipotleTweets @ChipotleTweets Becky is very nice                       Becky is very nice
2    Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at @ChipotleTweets    Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at
3    Considering walking to @.ChipotleTweets in my llama onesie.              Considering walking to in my llama onesie.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may change the pattern to match zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by `@` and one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) in `str_remove_all` to remove those substring

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
Customer %>%
     mutate(Cleaned_Tweet = str_remove_all(Tweet, "\\s*@\\S+"))
```

-output

```
 ID                                                                 Tweet                                         Cleaned_Tweet
1  1                    @ChipotleTweets @ChipotleTweets Becky is very nice                                    Becky is very nice
2  2 Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at @ChipotleTweets Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at
3  3           Considering walking to @.ChipotleTweets in my llama onesie.            Considering walking to in my llama onesie.
```

NOTE: `str_remove` just removes the first instance of match i.e. if there are more than one match in a single string, it skips the others and matches only the first.  We need `str_remove_all` for removing all instances of matching patterns.

#### data

```
Customer <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Tweet = c("@ChipotleTweets @ChipotleTweets Becky is very nice", 
"Happy Halloween! I now look forward to $3 booritos at @ChipotleTweets", 
"Considering walking to @.ChipotleTweets in my llama onesie."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: This is awesome and so simple - str_remove_all is all I was looking for ;p Thank you/!